# Yeoman grunt build does not throw any warning/error but the resulting dist is not working

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

In an angular application, I either do `grunt build` or `grunt serve:dist` to build my production files and deploy them on a remote server. Everything looks fine and I can't see any warning message in the yeoman logs. `yo doctor` is also happy ("Everything looks all right!").

The problem is, whenever I go to my `dist/index.html`, I get the following message from the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found).     http://localhost:9000/components/portal/portal.html
>
> Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:
>   components/portal/portal.html

`portal.html` being the first template to be displayed in the app **when it is not minified**. I am surprised that the app is trying to get a resource in `components/` since all the html should now be in `dist/index.html` right?

I am using Yeoman version 1.4.6 with the default `GruntFile.js` from the `angular` generator. More particularly, the `build` task is defined as follow:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);
```

What could possibly be the cause of my problem? Feel free to request more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Gruntfile.js` they say

```
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'
```

So the problem was that part of my project was located more than one level down the root. Changing `{,*/}*` by `**/*` in the tasks involved resolved the issue.